# Html.ActionLink does not display new lines

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have this problem

```
string text = Html.Raw(immobileTmp.Localita + "\n" + immobileTmp.PrezzoVendita).ToString();
@Html.ActionLink(text, "DettaglioImmobile", "Immobili", new { id = immobileTmp.Id }, null)
```

but then no new line is in output just `<br />` between the 2 strings.

Then I tried

```
string text = Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(immobileTmp.Localita + "\n" + immobileTmp.PrezzoVendita).Replace("\n", "<br/>")).ToHtmlString();
@Html.ActionLink(text, "DettaglioImmobile", "Immobili", new { id = immobileTmp.Id }, null)
```

but had no better luck.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to insert two `</ br>`, did you tried that ?

**UPDATE**

Try `Environment.NewLine`, like that:

```
string text = Html.Raw(immobileTmp.Localita + Environment.NewLine + immobileTmp.PrezzoVendita).ToString();
@Html.ActionLink(text, "DettaglioImmobile", "Immobili", new { id = immobileTmp.Id }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s1 = (immobileTmp.Localita).ToString() + " ";
String s2 = (immobileTmp.PrezzoVendita).ToString();
String s = s1 + s2

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

int i = 0;
while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + s1.Length)) != -1) {
    sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}

string text = Html.Raw(s);
```

Comment: Why are you replacing spaces with `br` tags? Why do you think this will help?

Comment: When it will find the space after the first `string`, it will replace it with `\n`. I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

If you join the strings with `Environment.NewLine` wrapping the tag in a `<pre>` splits the lines as you want, as in this sample:

```
@{
    string sep = Environment.NewLine;
    string text = Html.Raw(immobileTmp.Localita + sep + immobileTmp.PrezzoVendita).ToString();
}

<pre>
    @Html.ActionLink(text, "DettaglioImmobile", "Immobili", new { id = immobileTmp.Id }, null)
</pre>
```

Gotcha: the text will be formatted as monospaced (because of the `<pre>`) but CSS can take care of that (`<pre class="blah">...`).